# create a linear model with fixed weights in Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I want to create a linear network with a single layer under PyTorch, but I want the weights to be manually initialized and to remain fixed.

For example the values of the weights with the model:

```
layer = nn.Linear(4, 1, bias=False)
weights = tensor([[ 0.6],
                  [0.25],
                  [ 0.1],
                  [0.05]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

[image]

Is this achievable? If so, how can I do it? Or is there an alternative linear function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can freeze your layer by setting the [`requires_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad.html) to `False`:

```
layer.requires_grad_(False)
```

This way the gradients of the `layer`'s parameters won't get computed.

Or by directly defining so when initializing the parameter:

```
layer = nn.Linear(4, 1, bias=False)
layer.weight = nn.Parameter(weights, requires_grad=False)
```

Alternatively, given an input `x` shaped `(n, 4)`, you can compute the result with a simple matrix multiplication as:

```
>>> x@weights 
# equivalent to torch.matmul(x, weights)
```

Comment: and for the initialization of the weights? do I have to do the initialization inside the Class? because I have a model composed of several architectures... for the second solution ? what is the necessary shape of the matrix of weights ?

Comment: You can either of the two, assuming you have defined `weights` as you did in the question above.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: I did this and got `RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`. Does anyone have a workaround to use when I want to leave one layer's weights fixed to their initial values, but also when I get this error message?  [This thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-element-0-of-variables-does-not-require-grad-and-does-not-have-a-grad-fn/11074/16) says you can only set `requires_grad_(False)` on leaf nodes of the computation graph, and idk what exactly makes a leaf node.

Comment: What is your setup, could you provide a minimal example to reproduce the error you got? Leaf node means the tensor doesn't originate from an operation: so either an input or a parameter tensor that does not require gradient computation.